# How can i connect to a EC2 machine which is within a VPC being ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-vpc

I am trying my hands on VPC and ELB.

my question is .
when we create a EC2 instance in default VPC we have public ip attached to it and we can ssh into it.

BUT

When i create an instance with in a VPC there i don't see any public ip to ssh into .

so where can i find the public ip of the instance.so that i can ssh into

Also note what happens when: instance in a part of security group  attached to ELB.
setting an elastic ip to the instance is one part . What if auto scaling spins up another instance what happens then ?

if i need to deploy into the EC2 . how would i do it? how do i access the public ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an instance under public subnet it does not mean the instance will have public access automatically, you need to enable public IP during launch process if you want to do that after:

Select EC2 instance> Actions>Networking> Manage Ip Addresses. Then use the option "To add or edit an IPv4 public IP Allocate an Elastic IP to this instance or network interface".

Create an elastic IP
Navigate to Elastic IP address link> click Associate IP
Select the instance to associate IP and save.
Now you will have EC2 instance with public IP without restarting/deleting EC2 instance.

Comment: thank you for the answer. What about the new instance that are spun up by auto scaling?

Comment: these can be configured using the launch template, in the network interface enable public IP option

Comment: Thank you it worked for me. Is there any other advantages to using launch template over launch configurations.

Comment: launch templates are much easier to maintain, also you can see the version history and has more options than launch configuration